# knockout example template example not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In the following code why does the jquery template not render? I thought that the template was build in?  thank you

```
<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">

    <ul>

        {{each(index,friend) friends}}

        <li>${ friend.name }</li>

        {{/each}}
    </ul>

</script>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h1>details</h1>

        <p>first name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
        <p>last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

        <p>full name: <span data-bind ="text: fullName"></span></p>

        <h2>friends</h2>
        <div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>


        <script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">

            <ul>

                {{each(index,friend) friends}}

                <li>${ friend.name }</li>

                {{/each}}
            </ul>

        </script>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<script type ="text/javascript">

    function friend(name) {
        return {
            name: ko.observable(name)
        };
    }

    var viewModel ={
        firstName: ko.observable("bert"),
        lastName: ko.observable("smith"),
        friends:ko.observableArray([new friend('steve'),new friend('annie')])
    };

    viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    },viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery.tmpl support is built in however you need to reference jQuery and the jQuery.tmpl to make it work as stated in the documentation under: [Note 6: Using jQuery.tmpl, an external string-based template engine:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

> By default, Knockout comes with support for jquery.tmpl. **To use it,
>   you need to reference the following libraries, in this order:**

```
<!-- First jQuery -->     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Then jQuery.tmpl --> <script src="jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<!-- Then Knockout -->    <script src="knockout-x.y.z.js"></script>
```

If you reference all the dependencies your code should work fine: [Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jxKa/12/)

Comment: @Md.lbrahim thanks of the info. The `jquery.tmpl.js` link was broken in the fiddle, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a data object to your template.

```
data-bind="template: { name: 'friendsTemplate', data: $data }"
```

Look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html for details.

Is there a reason why you are using a jQuery Template?  The following is more in alignment with "typical" Knockout usage. Also you should only use external templates if there is reuse. This code could easily be inlined.

```
<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul data-bind="friends">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the template as it was used in an example and it was for learning.